# How can I download a file from the website with C#

Tags: c#, web

I want to download the website with C#. In the first picture, I select the file I want to download. In the second picture, I start the download process by pressing the download button and the download is successful and the download percentage is displayed in the progress bar. When I want to download a second file, the file is downloaded, but the download percentage is not displayed in the progress bar and the download is not complete. So the progress changed and completed methods do not work for the second time. can you help me where is the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwJGM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isgWa.png)

```
public void FileDownload(string URL, string DirectorytoDownload, string FileName)
        {


            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL), DirectorytoDownload + "/" + FileName);


        

        }
        private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pb_download.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            lbl_percentage.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " %";

        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

            btn_download.Enabled = true;
            lbl_status.Text = Downloaded;
        }
       
       public void Download()
        {
        int selectedrow=dgv_fileList.SelectedRows[0].Index;
        string DownloadAddres = "http://google.com/download/" + dgv_fileList.Rows[selectedrow].Cells["filename"].Value.ToString(); // website representation written
        FileDownload(DownloadAddres, System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), Path.GetFileName(DownloadAddres));
        }
```

Comment: I highly doubt your code does what you described in your question. You are calling an async function (webClient.DownloadFileAsync(..)) from a non-async function (FileDownload(..)). This should cause your ui-thread to be blocked until the download completes. Thus, all your label should show is '100%' - no actual progress steps. Read up on async-await in .net